# Update a column in a table based on values from another column in the same table

Tags: sql, sorting, stored-procedures, sql-update, etl

I am trying to update the `order_date` column in the following table. Here is the requirement: for each `Med_Number`, the `order_date` must be the earliest/initial `transaction_Date`.

Example for `Med_number = M001`, `order_date` must be 03/02/2019.

Table before update:

```
Med_Key | Patient_ID |Med_Num | Trans_Type | Trans_Date | Order_Date         
-----------------------------------------------------------
  1     | 13216584   | M001   |  P         | 03/02/2019 |
  2     | 13216584   | M001   |  R1        | 04/04/2019 |
  3     | 13216584   | M001   |  R2        | 05/04/2019 |
  4     | 13216584   | M001   |  D         | 02/04/2021 |
  5     | 76983231   | M002   |  P         | 01/04/2018 |
  6     | 76983231   | M002   |  R1        | 02/04/2018 |
  7     | 76983231   | M002   |  R2        | 03/04/2018 |
  8     | 76983231   | M002   |  D         | 04/04/2019 |
  9     | 93216548   | M003   |  P         | 08/04/2021 |
  10    | 93216548   | M003   |  R1        | 09/04/2021 |
  11    | 93216548   | M003   |  R2        | 10/04/2021 |
  12    | 93216548   | M003   |  D         | 10/04/2022 |
```

I tried using an update statement like this:

```
UPDATE Products.audit
SET Order_date = Transaction_Date
```

With this query, each row will have the same order date and transaction date. NO GO

I then manually updated each row with the following query

```
UPDATE Products.audit
SET Order_date = '03/02/2019'
WHERE med_key = '13216584-M001-R1' 
   OR med_Key = '13216584-M001-R2'
```

I had to repeat that for each `Med_Nunber`, works, but gets time consuming, would have done it this way if I only had few records.

My table has about 70000 distinct `Med_number`, so I cannot update the table manually

I need help with a query that will update the `order_date`. TIA

Table after Manual update

```
Med_Key | Patient_ID |Med_Num | Trans_Type | Trans_Date | Order_Date         
-----------------------------------------------------------
  1     | 13216584   | M001   |  P         | 03/02/2019 | 03/02/2019
  2     | 13216584   | M001   |  R1        | 04/04/2019 | 03/02/2019
  3     | 13216584   | M001   |  R2        | 05/04/2019 | 03/02/2019
  4     | 13216584   | M001   |  D         | 02/04/2021 | 03/02/2019
  5     | 76983231   | M002   |  P         | 01/04/2018 | 01/04/2018
  6     | 76983231   | M002   |  R1        | 02/04/2018 | 01/04/2018
  7     | 76983231   | M002   |  R2        | 03/04/2018 | 01/04/2018
  8     | 76983231   | M002   |  D         | 04/04/2019 | 01/04/2018
  9     | 93216548   | M003   |  P         | 08/04/2021 | 08/04/2021
  10    | 93216548   | M003   |  R1        | 09/04/2021 | 08/04/2021
  11    | 93216548   | M003   |  R2        | 10/04/2021 | 08/04/2021
  12    | 93216548   | M003   |  D         | 10/04/2022 | 08/04/2021
```

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question as editable text

Comment: Please read and edit your question appropriately ; [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please specify which DBMS you are using. SQL Server, MySQL 5.x, MySQL 8+, PostgreSQL, etc? They all have different syntax.

Comment: I am using SQL server 2019. Thank you

Comment: I added relevant information relevant table to the post, also I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You can use an updatable CTE.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
      MIN(Transaction_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Med_Number) AS MinTranDate
    FROM Products.audit
)
UPDATE cte
SET Order_date = MinTranDate;
```